# can i generate cPanel for my Digital Ocean Server?

Tags: php, server, cpanel, centos7, digital-ocean

I want to make a `Cpanel` of my Digital Ocean Server.

Currently, I'm using the Digital Ocean Server.

In this server, I create a droplet for storing the code of my website.

But I have some more requirements, like

- Project wise PHP `version` setup.

So, I want to customize `configuration` using `Cpanel` of Digital Ocean Server.

Comment: cpanel sucks, try virtualmin.com, i use that and it's very nice

Comment: Is this easy to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Installation procedure on cPanel's official website or Digital Ocean tutorials.

You can select different PHP versions for all the subdomains and addon domains via the Multi PHP function available in Cpanel.